# x86 confusion with lea instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

So `lea` instruction -- loads effective address -- suppose to be used to load up an address, but I'm kinda confused with this example,

```
lea (%edx, %ecx, 1), %eax
```

Is this instruction used to get a byte value of address (base `%edx` and offset `%ecx`)? If so, is it possible to use `mov` instruction instead of using `lea` in this case?

Comment: This particular command adds together EDX and ECX and assigns the result to EAX. MOV can't do that, neither can ADD. LEA can also add an extra constant and multiply the index by a small power of two.

Comment: Related: [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46597055)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak for the precise syntax; I'm used to MASM, which writes more or less the same information "backwards".

But in general the LEA instruction is used to compute addresses by combining values from base and index registers with various constants. In the general form what

```
     LEA  target_register, offset[base_register*k+index_register] ; MASM syntax, read from right to left
```

does is:

```
      target_register:=content(base_register)*k+content(index_register)+offset
```

where k is 0, 1, 2 or 4  (and if k is zero, we don't bother writing "base register*k").

This combines arithmetic and register-to-register moves, so if you had to implement it without using LEA, yes, you'd likely use a MOV instruction (and SHL and ADD...).   But LEA does NOT fetch anything from memory, and various forms of the MOV command do, so I don't think of LEA as a kind of MOV instruction.

Comment: Right, actually LEA is often used for simple arithmetics (as it doesn't update the flags), it's definitely not a load

Comment: (reg, reg, constant) in AT&T is same as offset[base+index] in MASM? i doubt it. But LEA does not fetch anything from memory for sure?

Comment: @Leeor: MOV doesn't update the flags either; what's your point?

Comment: @REALFREE:  LEA does what I wrote.  No memory access.  If you replaced the LEA with a MOV opcode, the instruction would compute the address for the target register exactly the same way, but then use that address to fetch a value from memory.

Comment: @Ira - I meant as opposed to ADD for e.g. - the point is that it's an arithmetic op, not a memory op

Comment: @REALFREE: I don't know what the AT&T syntax says exactly.  It has to fit into the structure of what I claim LEA does.

Comment: I guess you are right. So lea (%eax,%eax,1), %ecx is equivalent to lea ecx, [eax + eax*1]. So returning to my original question, it just calculates [eax + eax * 1] as address and put into ecx in this case?

Comment: That's probably what it does.  You need to consult your AT&T syntax reference to know for sure.

Comment: @REALFREE yes, the basic format for the memory operand is `offset(base, index, scale)` in att syntax. That being said you should really consider switching to intel syntax for readability. att is an abomination of assembly syntax IMO.

Comment: @greatwolf ah well I thought so at first time, but once you get used to it, it's alright imo xD