# Segmentation notation

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, intel-syntax

I am trying to understand some of the programs that were written for MS DOS. Does the instruction mov ax, ds:4Ch move the value of ds*16 + 4Ch or does it move the value stored at the address ds*16 + 4Ch?

Comment: The latter.  In fact, there is no direct way to load the value `ds*16 + 4Ch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a memory operand because it uses `ds:`.  MASM-style Intel syntax doesn't require `[]` around memory operands.

Also, there's no single machine instruction that will calculate a linear address in an integer register.  The whole point of segmentation is to deal with linear addresses that are too big for a single register.  You can do it manually if you want if you're in real mode (where the segment register value is the base, like `mov ax, ds` / `shl ax, 4`), but not as easily if the segment register value is just a selector.  286/386 protected mode, or Unreal mode.

`lea ax, [es: bx + si + 12]` for example *only* deals with offset calculations, ignoring the segment base.