# What IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA should be used for?

Tags: x86, profiling, instrumentation, intel-pin

I am willing to instrument `lea` instructions, followed by a call to `PIN_SafeCopy()` to capture the content of the memory. I tried with `IARG_MEMORY_READ_EA` but it did not work. So I move to `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` as it is written in the fine manual that it is usefull to instrument lea instructions.

But it is not working neither. Taking the following instruction:

```
 lea eax, ptr [r11+0x1]
```

The address I get with `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` is `0x00000088` which I cannot use with `PIN_SafeCopy()`

**My question is**: 
Is `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` intended to compute the effective address of a `lea` instruction (that is loaded into the register) or is it something else ?

I would understand that there is no real need to compute the effective address as it is the job of the instruction itself...still I want to make sure my understanding is correct.

**Bonus question**: what's the difference between `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA`|`IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA` and `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` represents the effective address of an explicit memory operand, which is a memory operand that is specified by dedicated bits in the instruction encoding. In x86, there can be at most one explicit memory operand. `lea` does have an explicit memory operand, but many other instructions may also have explicit memory operands. `push`, `pop`, and string instructions have implicit memory operands. `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` is only valid if `INS_HasExplicitMemoryReference` is `true`.

The essential difference between `lea` and other instructions that have memory operands is that `lea` does not use its memory operand to access memory. In fact, the effective address calculated using `lea` may not even be a memory address. [`lea` has advantages over other (combinations of) instructions for doing arithmetic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers) So if the effective address in `lea eax, ptr [r11+0x1]` is 0x00000088, then `lea`  is probably being used to just add `r11` and 0x1 and store the result in `eax`. The effective address is not actually being used to access memory (in a later instruction).

> My question is: Is IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA intended to compute the
>   effective address of a lea instruction (that is loaded into the
>   register) or is it something else ?

Yes, but not just `lea`. The effective address of any instruction with an explicit memory operand can be captured using `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` and passed to an analysis routine.

If you are only interested in `lea`, then use `INS_IsLea` before injecting a call to an analysis routine.

> Bonus question: what's the difference between
>   IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA|IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA and IARG_MEMORYOP_EA ?

There is no such a thing as `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA|IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA`. The value of `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA|IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA` may or may not be equal to `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` and it could mean any of the `IARG_*` arguments or nothing.

Note that `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA`, `IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA`, `IARG_MEMORYREAD2_EA`, and `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` represent explicit or implicit memory operands that are actually used by the instruction to access memory. `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA` is only valid if `INS_IsMemoryRead` is `true`. `IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA` is only valid if `INS_IsMemoryWrite` is `true`. `IARG_MEMORYREAD2_EA` is only valid if `INS_HasMemoryRead2` is `true`. Finally, `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` is only valid if at least one of `INS_IsMemoryRead` or `INS_IsMemoryWrite` are `true`.

Comment: I don't understand "There is no such a thing as IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA|IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA." Maybe I should have used "," instead of "|"

Comment: @Heyji Oh OK. `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA` represents a memory operand from which the instruction *reads*. `IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA` represents a memory operand from which the instruction *writes*. `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` means read or write.

Comment: @Haidi Brais, I see. So IARG_MEMORYOP_EA is a commodity to deal with memory operands at once, whatever it is read, write or both. It came after, IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA and IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA isn't it ?

Comment: @Heyji Yes. But what do you by "It came after"?

Comment: @Haidi Brais when I started using pin, ten years ago, IARG_MEMORYOP_EA was not available in the ARG API. Only IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA and IARG_MEMORYWRITE_EA.

Comment: @Heyji OK. `IARG_MEMORYOP_EA` has been supported since at least Pin 2.11.

Comment: @HadiBrais Hi, so can I say it's possible that both `IARG_EXPLICIT_MEMORY_EA` and `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA` can produce same memory address? I'm making reference counter for specifc memory address, so I'm afraid that I can capture duplicated addresses. Thanks!

Comment: @Feng.Ma Yes, for example a MOV instruction that reads from memory into a register. If you want to count the number of memory operands that are read from memory, you can use `IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA`, `IARG_MEMORYREAD2_EA`, and `IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA`. This would exclude LEA, which doesn't actually access memory.