# Trying to obtain addq, but keep getting leaq

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, compiler-optimization

So, I'm trying to get familiar with assembly and trying to reverse-engineer some code. My problem lies in trying to decode addq which I understands performs Source + Destination= Destination.

I am using the assumptions that parameters x, y, and z are passed in registers %rdi, %rsi, and %rdx. The return value is stored in %rax.

```
long someFunc(long x, long y, long z){
1.  long temp=(x-z)*x;
2.  long temp2= (temp<<63)>>63;
3.  long temp3= (temp2 ^ x);
4.  long answer=y+temp3; 
5.  return answer;
}
```

So far everything above line 4 is exactly what I am wanting. However, line 4 gives me `leaq    (%rsi,%rdi), %rax` rather than  `addq    %rsi, %rax`. I'm not sure if this is something I am doing wrong, but I am looking for some insight.

Comment: I fixed the code in my question. I ended up shortening the temps and such.

Comment: For me `gcc -O0` or `gcc -O3 -march=atom` produces an `add`.

Comment: @Jester: Interesting.  But instead of doing better register allocation, it uses an extra `mov` before `add`.  That might still be better than LEA on in-order Atom; it runs LEA on the actual AGU hardware earlier in the pipeline, so inputs need to be ready sooner, like a couple cycle IIRC.  So in this chain of dependent operations, it could introduce a 2 cycle stall vs. just 1 extra cycle of `mov` latency.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions aren't equivalent.  For LEA, `rax` is a pure output.  For your hoped-for `add`, it's `rax += rsi` so the compiler would have to `mov %rdi, %rax` first.  That's less efficient so it doesn't do that.

**`lea` is a totally normal way for compilers to implement `dst = src1 + src2`, saving a `mov` instruction.**  In general don't expect C operators to compile to instruction named after them.  Especially small left-shifts and add, or multiply by 3, 5, or 9, because those are prime targets for optimization with LEA.  e.g. `lea (%rsi, %rsi, 2), %rax` implements `result = y*3`.  See [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers) for more.  LEA is also useful to avoid destroying either of the inputs, if they're both needed later.

---

Assuming you meant `t3` to be the same variable as `temp3`, clang *does* compile the way you were expecting, doing a better job of register allocation so it can use a shorter and more efficient `add` instruction without any extra `mov` instructions, instead of needing `lea`.

**Clang chooses to do better register allocation than GCC** so it can just use `add` instead of needing `lea` for the last instruction.  (**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'long+someFunc(long+x,+long+y,+long+z)%7B%0A++long+temp1%3D(x-z)*x%3B%0A++long+temp2%3D+(temp1%3C%3C63)%3E%3E63%3B%0A++long+temp3%3D+(temp2+%5E+x)%3B%0A++long+answer%3Dy%2Btemp3%3B+%0A++return+answer%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.32428278645868,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:diff,i:(lhs:1,rhs:2),l:'5',n:'0',o:'Diff+x86-64+clang+9.0.0+vs+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:36.32428278645868,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171'),(name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.51876622195926,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'171'),(name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.15695099158205,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)**).  This saves code-size (because of the indexed addressing mode), and `add` has slightly better throughput than LEA on most CPUs, like 4/clock instead of 2/clock.

Clang also optimized the shifts into `andl $1, %eax` / `negq %rax` to create the 0 or `-1` result of that arithmetic right shift = bit-broadcast.  It also optimized to 32-bit operand-size for the first few steps because the shifts throw away all but the low bit of `temp1`.

```
# side by side comparison, like the Godbolt diff pane
clang:                           |    gcc:
        movl    %edi, %eax              movq    %rdi, %rax
        subl    %edx, %eax              subq    %rdx, %rdi
        imull   %edi, %eax              imulq   %rax, %rdi  # temp1

        andl    $1, %eax                salq    $63, %rdi
        negq    %rax                    sarq    $63, %rdi   # temp2

        xorq    %rdi, %rax              xorq    %rax, %rdi  # temp3

        addq    %rsi, %rax              leaq    (%rdi,%rsi), %rax   # answer
        retq                            ret
```

Notice that clang chose `imul  %edi, %eax` (into RAX) but GCC chose to multiply into RDI.  That's the difference in register allocation that leads to GCC needing an `lea` at the end instead of an `add`.

Compilers sometimes even get stuck with an extra `mov` instruction at the end of a small function when they make poor choices like this, if the last operation wasn't something like addition that can be done with `lea` as a non-destructive op-and-copy.  These are missed-optimization bugs; you can report them on GCC's bugzilla.

---

**Other missed optimizations**

GCC and clang could have optimized by using `and` instead of `imul` to set the low bit only if both inputs are odd.

Also, since only the low bit of the `sub` output matters, XOR (add without carry) would have worked, or even addition!  (Odd+-even = odd.  even+-even = even.  odd+-odd = odd.)  That would have allowed an `lea` instead of `mov/sub` as the first instruction.

```
        lea    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
        and    %edi, %eax           # low bit matches (x-z)*x

        andl    $1, %eax            # keep only the low bit
        negq    %rax                # temp2
```

Lets make a truth table for the low bits of `x` and `z` to see how this shakes out if we want to optimize more / differently:

```
# truth table for low bit: input to shifts that broadcasts this to all bits
 x&1  |  z&1  | x-z = x^z | x*(x-z) = x & (x-z)
  0       0          0       0
  0       1          1       0
  1       0          1       1
  1       1          0       0
                            x & (~z) = BMI1 andn
```

So `temp2 = (x^z) & x & 1 ? -1 : 0`.  But also `temp2 = -((x & ~z) & 1)`. 
 We can rearrange that to `-((x&1) & ~z)` which lets us start with `not z` and `and $1, x` in parallel, for better ILP.  Or if `z` might be ready first, we could do operations on it and shorten the critical path from `x` -> `answer`, at the expense of `z`.

Or with a [BMI1 `andn`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn) instruction which does `(~z) & x`, we can do this in one instruction.  (Plus another to isolate the low bit)

I think this function has the same behaviour for every possible input, so compilers *could have* emitted it from your source code.  **This is one possibility you *should* wish your compiler emitted:**

```
# hand-optimized
# long someFunc(long x, long y, long z)
someFunc:
        not    %edx                   # ~z
        and    $1, %edx
        and    %edi, %edx             # x&1 & ~z = low bit of temp1
        neg    %rdx                  # temp2 = 0 or -1

        xor    %rdi, %rdx            # temp3 = x or ~x

        lea    (%rsi, %rdx), %rax    # answer = y + temp3
        ret
```

So there's still no ILP, unless `z` is ready before `x` and/or `y`.  Using an extra `mov` instruction, we could do `x&1` in parallel with `not z`

Possibly you could do something with `test`/`setz` or `cmov`, but IDK if that would beat lea/and (temp1) + and/neg (temp2) + xor + add.

I haven't looked into optimizing the final xor and add, but note that `temp3` is basically a conditional NOT of `x`.  You could maybe improve latency at the expense of throughput by calculating both ways at once and selecting between them with cmov.  Possibly by involving the 2's complement identity that `-x - 1 = ~x`.  Maybe improve ILP / latency by doing `x+y` and then correcting that with something that depends on the x and z condition?  Since we can't subtract using LEA, it seems best to just NOT and ADD.

```
# return y + x  or   y + (~x) according to the condition on x and z
someFunc:
        lea    (%rsi, %rdi), %rax     # y + x

        andn   %edi, %edx, %ecx       # ecx = x & (~z)

        not    %rdi                   # ~x
        add    %rsi, %rdi             # y + (~x)

        test    $1, %cl
        cmovnz  %rdi, %rax            # select between y+x and y+~x
        retq
```

This has more ILP, but needs BMI1 `andn` to still be only 6 (single-uop) instructions.  Broadwell and later have single-uop CMOV; on earlier Intel it's 2 uops.

The other function could be 5 uops using BMI `andn`.

In this version, the first 3 instructions can all run in the first cycle, assuming x,y, and z are all ready.  Then in the 2nd cycle, ADD and TEST can both run.  In the 3rd cycle, CMOV can run, taking integer inputs from LEA, ADD, and flag input from TEST.  So the total latency from x->answer, y->answer, or z->answer is 3 cycles in this version.  (Assuming single-uop / single-cycle cmov).  Great if it's on the critical path, not very relevant if it's part of an independent dep chain and throughput is all that matters.

vs. 5 (andn) or 6 cycles (without) for the previous attempt.  Or even worse for the compiler output using `imul` instead of `and` (3 cycle latency just for that instruction).

Comment: So, if I was trying to get the equivalent line from Clang in gcc is there anything that can be done differently?

Comment: @letsgetphysical: not really, unless you want to dig into GCC's source code and figure out how to teach its register allocation code to find this missed-optimization.  Or Jester points out that `-mtune=atom` will make it use `mov` to RAX + `add`, but I don't see how that's any different from `lea`.  And it will make GCC *prefer* lea over add in other cases.  If you care about this level of detail in how your C turns into asm, maybe you need to do it yourself by hand.  I'm not sure what your goal is, or why you'd care.  You could maybe hack GCC to never use LEA and make slower code...

Comment: I'm just trying to ensure that I'm interpreting the assembly asm correctly.

Comment: @letsgetphysical: Compilers will frequently use LEA as a copy-and-add.  Don't expect an actual `add` instruction; in other cases it's *not* the best choice.

Comment: Understood. I ended up removing some of my variable declaration statements and instead changed the values of x, y, and z and it changed to addq.

Comment: @letsgetphysical: updated my answer to say more clearly that you should not in general expect C operators to compile to the asm instruction of the same name.  And added some hand-optimized versions that significantly transform the logic, partly for the sake of it as a demonstration, and also to create a lower-latency version.