# Can MOVing and using and SUB or ADD replace using LEA in some cases?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Is doing `LEA RDI, [RBP - 8]` the same as doing

```
   MOV RDI, RBP
   SUB RDI, 8
```

Comment: Yes it is, except for the effect on flags.

Comment: It produces the same result, but using lea takes 3 fewer bytes.  There may also be a (microscopic) difference in performance, plus the effect on the flags.

Comment: Basically yes, LEA is just a shift-and-add instruction.  One of the few math instructions that don't affect FLAGS at all (others including `not` and `loop`), but if you don't need an exact drop-in replacement then yeah. [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597375)