# LEA vs MOV + INC for incrementing a variable and storing it in another one?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, micro-optimization

What's the difference between

```
lea r12, [rsi + 1]
```

and

```
mov r12, rsi
inc r12
```

Is one advantageous over the other (performance-wise)?

Comment: Well, for starters, the first one is 4 bytes of code and the second is 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LEA is shorter machine code and only 1 uop instead of 2, and 1 cycle latency without relying on mov-elimination (disabled on Ice Lake).  It's pretty clearly better on all existing microarchitectures (https://uops.info/ / https://agner.org/optimize/), which is why compilers use it when you compile `int foo(int x){ return x+1; }`

See also [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers)

---

And re: counting uops and so on in general, *[What considerations go into predicting latency for operations on modern superscalar processors and how can I calculate them by hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607391/what-considerations-go-into-predicting-latency-for-operations-on-modern-supersca)*

`inc` specifically has a minor performance downside on Alder Lake E-cores or other Silvermont-family CPUs because of its partial-flag handling.  *[INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095)*

`lea` doesn't affect FLAGS, which can occasionally be helpful with the surrounding code.  Modern CPUs can rename FLAGS as many times per cycle as the pipeline width, so it's not generally a problem to write FLAGS other than `adc` loops or other special cases.

Comment: I'd normally just post a quick comment while I look for a duplicate, but apparently [moderators would rather we post everything useful as answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419996/224132), no matter how short.

Comment: @prl: True, and `inc` specifically has a minor performance downside on Alder Lake E-cores or other Silvermont-family CPUs because of its partial-flag handling.  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095)